# How to add promise to return so $.when and .then function properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am having an issue caused by asynchronous Javascript execution.  I am attempting to set the value of a variable using a function, and then use that variable in a function call immediatly after. I want to implement JQuery .when and .then to solve this issue, but I am having trouble with how to impement the promise necessary for .then to know when to begin execution.

Here is what I have:

```
function addSerialNumber(item_id) {
    var serialNumberList;
    var serialNumber = $("serial-number").val();

    $.when(serialNumberList = addSerialFunc(item_id, serialNumber))
    .then(alert("Serial number successfully added."), 
        insertTransaction(item_id, serialNumberList));
}

function addSerialFunc(item_id, serialNumber) {
    var serialNumberList = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "someRandom.jsp",
        data: {wsFunction: "Insert", item_id: item_id, serialNumber: serialNumber},
        async: false
    }).done(function(xml){
        $(xml).find("Item").each(function() {
            insert_id = ($(this).find("SendBack_CD").text());

            if (!runError(insert_id, item_id)) {
                //Fail
            } else {
                //Success
                serialNumberList.push(insert_id);
            }
        })
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error occured! Type: " + textStatus + " HTTP Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
    });

    return serialNumberList;
}
```

I am trying to create serialNumberList by calling addSerialFunc(), and then use serialNumberList as an argument for insertTransaction(). This works sometimes, but I intermittently get

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined`

because it is trying to execute insertTransaction() before serialNumberList has been populated by addSerialFunc().

How can I implement a promise in addSerialFunc() so that the .then knows when to begin execution?

Comment: Quite a few problems there!

Comment: Are you using jQuery 3? Or else, can you?

Comment: Never use `done` and `fail`, always use `then` and `catch`.

Comment: Don't use `$.when`. It's no magic. The `addSerialFunc` that you are calling must `return` a promise or you won't be able to chain a `then` invocatin onto it.

Comment: I'm using JQuery 1.9. But I will see if I can adapt the solution to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- In the `addSerialFunc` you return a value synchronously, but it will only be populated later, when the response comes in from the asynchronous ajax call. Instead you should return the promise *returned* by `$.ajax`.
- you call `alert` immediately, instead of passing a callback function to `then`.
- you pass a second argument to `then`, which again is not a function for the same reason as in the previous point. But also, the second argument should be a function for when the promise rejects.

So, this should work better -- it assumes jQuery version 3.x:

```
function addSerialNumber(item_id) {
    var serialNumberList;
    var serialNumber = $("serial-number").val();

    // *** $.when is not needed
    addSerialFunc(item_id, serialNumber) // *** start with the returned promise
    .then(function (serialNumberList) { // pass a function(!), which gets the value as argument
        alert("Serial number successfully added."); 
        insertTransaction(item_id, serialNumberList);
    }).catch(function (err) { // better to also have a `catch` call here
        console.log(err);
        console.log("because of error, no transaction is inserted");
    });
}

function addSerialFunc(item_id, serialNumber) {    
    return $.ajax({
//  ^^^^^^
        type: "post",
        url: "someRandom.jsp",
        data: {wsFunction: "Insert", item_id: item_id, serialNumber: serialNumber}
        /* drop the `async` property */
    }).then(function(xml){
 //    ^^^^
        var serialNumberList = new Array(); // *** define here
        $(xml).find("Item").each(function() {
            var insert_id = ($(this).find("SendBack_CD").text());
    //      ^^^^ make sure to always define the scope of your variables!
            if (!runError(insert_id, item_id)) {
                //Fail
                throw "Some error occurred"; // *** adapt message here
                ^^^^^^
            } else {
                //Success
                serialNumberList.push(insert_id);
            }
        });
        return serialNumberList; // *** return!!!!
    }).catch(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 //    ^^^^^
        console.log("Error occured! Type: " + textStatus + " HTTP Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
        throw errorThrown; // *** cascade the error
    });
}
```

Comment: Btw, you also might want to drop the `async: false` and the unnecessary `$.when`

Comment: Thanks for this! I am going to mark this as the correct answer. Hopefully I can adapt this to work with JQuery 1.9.

Comment: For jQuery 1.9: If you you have support for the native `Promise` object, then you can wrap the `$.ajax(...)` call in `Promise.resolve($.ajax(....))` so that you can use `then` and `catch` on it with native support. There would be just one argument passed to the `catch` callback.